# Getting the full JSON path in handlebars

Tags: json, path, handlebars.js, helper

I'm using handlebars to template and i need to find a way to reference back to the source json file at run time in the browser. The easiest way i can think of doing this is to store the value's json path in a data-attribute tag but i can't find a simple way to generate this path, is there anything built into handlebars that i've overlooked?

**Handlebars**

```
{{#each this.body}}
    <div>
        {{#if this.header}}
            <h4 data-Path="Some way to generate path here">{{{this.header.output}}}</h4>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

**Output:**

```
<h4 data-Path="Content.body[0].header.output">Some random output</h4>
```

If there's any other way i could reference back to json i'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You know the structure of JSON already. You just need the index of each iteration.

In that case you can use `{{@index}}` to get the index of current iteration.

```
<h4 data-Path="Content.body[{{@index}}].header.output">
```

[Read more...](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html)

Comment: There are more nested partials than i've shown, so i'd need references to all the @ index's from loops above also, that's why i was hoping there was a simple @path value or something.